# How to install zpanel 10.1.1 for Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, server, software-installation

All related questions for *Zpanel Installation* are outdated and those links are not working so I am posting new question

This is [Zpanel GitHub](https://github.com/zpanel/installers) link.

It have Installed Ubuntu server on *Amazon EC2* , and in above link there are installation command but when I tried running that it is not working.

I have curl Installed, It is fresh Installation of Ubuntu with No Modules Installed before as instructed on Zpanel website.

for Zpanel Installation below is command they gave for *Ubuntu 12.04 OS* . But its now working or I am doing it wrong most Probably.

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh)
```

Totally new to ubuntu that's why not getting this, how to Install using above command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just open a terminal and copy and paste the command:

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh)
```

and this will run quietly till end.

Else if you want to do it yourself:

first download the script

```
wget https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh
```

Then make the script executable

```
chmod +x 10_1_1.sh
```

Then run the script

```
sudo ./10_1_1.sh
```

I advise you just to use the first command and all things will be done automatically.

Comment: `bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory` I got this error for first command

Comment: ok try the next method

Comment: second one is working , Great!!

Comment: Glad to be able to help

Comment: It was bug from zpanel and it is fixed now. Both Methods Work.