# syntax error near unexpected token newline' doctype html ' while installing zpanel

Tags: server, software-installation, scripts

I am new to `ubuntu`, trying to install `zpanel` on my VPS server. Found some questions with same problem, but none of them was applicable in my case.

I have followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430231/how-to-install-zpanel-10-1-1-for-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts) to install `zpanel`,

first download the script

```
wget https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh
```

Then make the script executable

```
chmod +x 10_1_1.sh
```

Then run the script

```
sudo ./10_1_1.sh
```

it worked till I run the script.After executing the script,when I run it,I get this error on my putty

```
./10_1_1.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./10_1_1.sh: line 4: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` line is a `DOCTYPE` declaration for `HTML` documents, so it looks like you are fetching a web page instead of the script. Either open the script link in your browser and copy-paste the script source manually into a text file and save it as "`10_1_1.sh`" in your terminal's working directory, or try to use `curl` in place of `wget` (in either cases you can then follow the other instructions):

```
curl -o 10_1_1.sh https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is because of permission issues, so use the `Authorization` header with the `wget` command.

Example:

```
wget --header="Authorization: Basic A2l0Y99uLmlxQGhh" "https://mysite.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/1841544/US_export_policy.jar"
```

Here `A2l0Y99uLmlxQGhh` is the base64 of `username:password`.

To convert the `username:password` to base64 use the command below (in Unix systems only):

```
printf '%s' 'user:password' | base64
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but `wget` succeeds, so why would you change this command?